# Bowed Edge from Table Saw

Tags: table-saw

It has been a while since I've used my table saw, so, while I once new my way around it pretty well, I'm rusty now.

I started with a 40 inch long by 15 inch wide sheet of 18 mm Baltic Birch. I set my fence 1-/1/2 inch from the blade and ripped a few 40 inch long strips. I checked that the fence was parallel when I closed the lever by raising the blade to full height and measuring the distance on both the front and back edge of the blade. when making the cut, I was careful to keep the board flush with the fence. I did not use a feather board.

Later, I noticed the new edges were bowed. Next to a straight edge, the center is a little over 1/8-th inch off from straight.

I'm using a thin finishing blade, if that matters.

What could I be doing wrong, either in making the cut or aligning the saw?

Comment: Are you sure you had a straight edge against the fence? Could it have been bowed already?

Comment: No, I didn't check it. That's possible. Next ime I do it, I'll check. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to ask this instead on https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn’t know about that one. Thank you.